# Unable to unmarshal JSON array in Golang

Tags: http, go, unmarshalling

I am getting the below response in a URL and I want to unmarshal it, but I am unable to do so.
This is the kind of response that I'd like to unmarshal.

```
[
  {"title": "Angels And Demons", "author":"Dan Brown", "tags":[{"tagtitle":"Demigod", "tagURl": "/angelDemon}] }
  {"title": "The Kite Runner", "author":"Khalid Hosseinei", "tags":[{"tagtitle":"Kite", "tagURl": "/kiteRunner"}] }
  {"title": "Dance of the dragons", "author":"RR Martin", "tags":[{"tagtitle":"IronThrone", "tagURl": "/got"}] }
]
```

I am trying to unmarshal this sort of response but not being able to do so. This is the code that I am trying to write.

```
res, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "error": err,
    }).Fatal("Couldn't get the html response")
}
defer res.Body.Close()
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "error": err,
    }).Fatal("Couldn't read the response")
}

s := string(b)

var data struct {
    Content []struct {
        Title           string   `json:"title"`
        Author          string   `json:"author"`
        Tags            map[string]string   `json:"tags"`
    }
}

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data); err != nil {
    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "error": err,
    }).Error("Un-marshalling could not be done.")
}

fmt.Println(data.Content)
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message you're receiving?

Comment: error="json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct { Content []struct

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
var data struct {
    Content []struct {
        Title           string   `json:"title"`
        Author          string   `json:"author"`
        Tags            map[string]string   `json:"tags"`
    } }
```

to this

```
type Content struct {
        Title           string   `json:"title"`
        Author          string   `json:"author"`
        Tags            map[string]string   `json:"tags"`

}
var data []Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider unmarshalling it into a slice of Content:

```
type Content struct {
    Title  string            `json:"title"`
    Author string            `json:"author"`
    Tags   map[string]string `json:"tags"`
}

// Send in your json
func convertToContent(msg string) ([]Content, error) {
    content := make([]Content, 0, 10)

    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(msg)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(buf)

    err := decoder.Decode(&content)
    return content, err
}
```

Check out an example with your use case here: http://play.golang.org/p/TNjb85XjpP

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out this issue by doing a simple amendment in the above code.

```
var Content []struct {
    Title           string   `json:"title"`
    Author          string   `json:"author"`
    Tags            map[string]string   `json:"tags"`
}
```

Thanks for all your responses.